# Send couple 'fieldId : fieldValue' extjs ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I want to submit my form in an ajax request like this :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
 url:'myscript.py', 
 method: 'POST',          
 params: { firstfieldId:value , secondfieldId:value , ... },
 scope:this
});
```

So I'd like to create the `params` config manually from looping through my form fields and creating the dictionnary `fieldId : value`

How can I do this please?

Comment: check [getFieldvalues](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getFieldValues)

Comment: thanks but in case of a `radiogroup` field, it returns the id of the radiogroup, not the id of the checked radiofield inside it...

Comment: What did you do to try and get the `radiogroup` value?

Comment: you could iterate through the items defined in the form if there is a specific behaviour you'd like. Example:`Ext.each(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('MyForm')[0].items.items,function(item){console.log(item.name);console.log(item.getValue()); });`